# ef core create one single table without migrations

Tags: entity-framework

Basically my existing EF Core database is created via `EnsureCreatedAsync()` without any migrations, and now I have to create a new single table which is in `DbSet<Model>` inside the DbContext class. How do I do this? I've tried the following

```
        RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator =
            (RelationalDatabaseCreator)_dbContext.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
```

but it only contains methods for creating an entire database. Also my existing database already contains information that I wont be able to just drop.